# only change or refresh contact page and stable menu in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't want to change Common Menu Page and want to refresh contact page. 
If click to menu link, Menu page don't want to change, only change contact page.

Comment: Please explain better what you are trying to do? the above question doesn't really make sense.  What have you tried? can you show code? and example of what output you are getting and what you expect/want?

Comment: if change other controller, the menu don't want to change or refresh and only change contact page frame

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want only part of the page to update when moving through routes (urls). Make sure you're using

```
<%= yield %>
```

somewhere in your application layout file and that controller templates (app/views/...) don't include the menu themselves.

Example:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>Menu item 1</li>
      <li>Menu item 2</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="container">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: That source is not OK. because if call to other controller, the menu shows same result. But i don't want to refresh menu list, only change contanct.

Comment: If you don't want a page reload, then this is more of a javascript / ajax question, and not a Rails question. You may still read a bit about Rails with Turbolinks, which might be a 'mix' of both subjects.

Comment: please share your advise